# general bivalence for aromatic groups in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to draw the general bivalent naphthalene with `\chemfig` (image attached). And I cannot figure out how to make the two dangling bonds.

[image: What I would like to get]

My code only let me draw naphthalene, and as soon as I add a bond it attaches it to the naphthalene (which I don't want). Any suggestion?

Here is where I am at `\chemfig{[:0]*6(=-*6(-=-=-)=-=-)}` (which draws naphthalene only).

Here is the compilable source code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\title{naphthalene}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}

%Regular naphthalene
\chemfig{[:0]*6(=-*6(-=-=-)=-=-)}

%Bad way around because (1) the bond ends up at atom of aromatic group instead of in the middle of the bond. (2) on the other side it's only on the atom, does not go to the middle of the aromatic group
\chemfig{-([:0]*6(=-*6(-=-(-)=-)=-=-))-}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of section "12.6  Center of rings" (currently on page 20) of the `chemfig` manual:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{[:0]*6(=-*6(-=-=-)=-=-)}
\chemmove{%
\node[at=(cyclecenter1)](){}node [at=(cyclecenter1),shift=(180:1.75cm)](end){};
\draw[-,shorten <=.5cm](cyclecenter1)--(end);
\node[at=(cyclecenter2)](){}node [at=(cyclecenter2),shift=(0:1.75cm)](end){};
\draw[-,shorten <=.45cm](cyclecenter2)--(end);}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks so much! Sorry I did look through the manual and missed it. My bad . 
Manual : http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf